# Avoid inbuilt Grouping and creating sets in Cognos

Tags: sql, cognos

I have to group the age based on following criteria:

```
case
when [AGE] >= 0 and [AGE] <6 then 'UNDER 6 YRS'
when [AGE] >= 6 and [AGE] < 18 then '06 - 17 YRS'
when [AGE] >= 18 and [AGE] < 22 then '18 - 21 YRS'
*when [AGE] >= 0 and [AGE] < 21 then 'UNDER 21 YRS'
when [AGE] >= 22 and [AGE] < 46 then '22 - 45 YRS'
when [AGE] >= 46 and [AGE] < 56 then '46 - 55 YRS'
when [AGE] >= 56 and [AGE] < 65 then '56 - 64 YRS'
when [AGE] >= 64 then 'OVER 64 YRS'
*when [AGE] >= 21 then 'OVER 21 YRS'
else NULL
end
```

I can get all other age group apart from 2 conditions marked with astrick* because 'UNDER 21 YRS' and 'OVER 21 YRS' have already been grouped previously.
How can I get the data across all groups?

Comment: then remove first 3 cases

Comment: Different groups overlap.  That makes it unclear what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

one way workaround this is to separate them into two column :

```
select case
when [AGE] >= 0 and [AGE] <6 then 'UNDER 6 YRS'
when [AGE] < 18 then '06 - 17 YRS'
when [AGE] < 22 then '18 - 21 YRS'
when [AGE] < 46 then '22 - 45 YRS'
when [AGE] < 56 then '46 - 55 YRS'
when [AGE] < 65 then '56 - 64 YRS'
when [AGE] >= 64 then 'OVER 64 YRS'
else NULL
end
, case when [AGE] >= 0 and [AGE] < 21 then 'UNDER 21 YRS'
       when [AGE] >= 21 then 'OVER 21 YRS'
else null
end
from ...
```

as you can see you can simplify your query by removing greater than condition since it's already been checked in previous case when statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want one column (AgeGroup?), you'll need two queries and UNION them together.

Unless AGE can be negative, your expressions for this data item should be...

```
case
  when [AGE] < 6 then 'UNDER 6 YRS'
  when [AGE] < 18 then '06 - 17 YRS'
  when [AGE] < 22 then '18 - 21 YRS'
  when [AGE] < 46 then '22 - 45 YRS'
  when [AGE] < 56 then '46 - 55 YRS'
  when [AGE] < 65 then '56 - 64 YRS'
  else 'OVER 64 YRS'
end
```

...in one query and...

```
case
  when [AGE] < 21 then 'UNDER 21 YRS'
  else 'OVER 21 YRS'
end
```

...in the other.

This will result in two rows for each [row] in your current output.  (For example, two rows for each person.)  But that seems to be what you're asking for.

If you need two columns (AgeGroup1 and AgeGroup2), use the answer from @eshirvana.